# Switching from CDN to NPM for Google Maps JavaScript MarkerClusterer. How?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am currently loading Google Maps JavaScript MarkerClusterer from CDN. I am trying to switch to the NPM version (to get some Typescript checking in my JavaScript files), but I do not understand how. The [documentation](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer) seems to assume I do understand how. It just says I should use this line after installing the NPM version:

```js
import { MarkerClusterer } from "@googlemaps/markerclusterer";
```

But Google Chrome disagrees and says

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@googlemaps/markerclusterer". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install

```sh
npm i @googlemaps/markerclusterer -D
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/markerclusterer

Comment: Thanks, but that is what the documentation page I linked to says. So I have done that already.

Comment: can you publish your package-lock.json?

Comment: Please tell me what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think your project has a package.json file, normal use of `npm install` will generate a package-lock.json file.

Comment: That does not sound correct. Where did you get that info?

Comment: Hi, Did you find answer?